# weighted graph plot

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there a program to visualize weighted graphs in a way, that the weights are represented in the layout of the graph?
eg. edges with a high weight are shorter and edges with low weight are longer?

I don't want (only) the edge-thickness to represent the weights.

Comment: I don't think this question is on topic for MathOverflow. It may be a better fit at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization

Comment: Note that the triangular inequality may be an obstruction to the construction of such a visualization, depending on the weights and the precise relation you want between weights and length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost every advanced graph drawing package has implemented one or more force-directed layout algorithms, which almost all permit adjustments to the repulsion by edge weights.  One is [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), which permits one to alter the layout parameters interactively:

---

[image] 

          
<sup>(Image source: 
[ForceAtlas2](https://gephi.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/forceatlas2-the-new-version-of-our-home-brew-layout/))</sup>

---